# How to run an exe file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I know lot of people ask this question in stackoverflow. I tried to get idea from it but I face some error.

below is my code

```
import subprocess
command = ''
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
# subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)

# subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /IM rufus.exe', startupinfo=startupinfo)
subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/IM' , 'rufus.exe' , '/F'] , shell=True)
```

It give me the error `rufus.exe` not found and when I gave it complete path. It gave me error Invalid args

Comment: I use double slashes "c:\\direct\\direct2\\rufus.exe"

Comment: @PatrickArtner bro i use r"c:\direct\direct2\rufus.exe" it gave me error ERROR: Invalid query

Comment: @agastya i gave the pull path within the quotes still gave an error "ERROR: The process D:/Pycharm_project/Run_exe/rufus.exe" not found."

Comment: Maybe with os it will work ?

Comment: @TheMachinist bro can you gave me short example

Comment: import os / 

os.system("echo Hello world !")

Try with this : https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-python/